# Gimp make top half of photo lighter, and bottom half darker

Tags: color, gimp, photo-editing

[image: Stairway up]

I have a need to show things more dark or "dreary" at the bottom part/half of the stairway, and more light at the top.  At the top I don't care about the stair colors so much, I want the sun to be even brighter.   So ideally I have "dark weather" at the bottom of the stairs, and even "brighter weather" at the top.  Are you able to tell me how to do this, and/or modify the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rather simple method to darken parts of an image only would be to apply the *Blend Tool* with a white to black soft gradient in *Subtract* blend mode. We can also play with settings for opacity to fine tune the desired effect.

[image]
Linear Blend, Subtract Mode, 70% Opacity

[image]
Radial Blend, Subtract Mode, 70% Opacity

To add even more dramatic effects, and to brighten the sunny areas we can in addition adjust *Color > Curves...* with an S-shaped value curve:

[image]
Linear blend, adjusted.

[image]
Radial blend, adjusted.

**Note:** Above examples are rather exaggerated for better demontrating the effect. With a more cautious application of both, blend and color curves results may become more "natural".